# SOLR mysolr pysolr Python 401 reply

Tags: python, solr, http-status-code-401

If there is someone out there who has already worked with SOLR and a python library to index/query solr, would you be able to try and answer the following question.

I am using the mySolr python library but there are others out (like pysolr) there and I don't think the problem is related to the library itself.

I have a default multicore SOLR setup, **so no authentication required normally**. Don't need it to access the admin page at `http://localhost:8080/solr/testcore/admin/` either

```
from mysolr import Solr
solr = Solr('http://localhost:8080/solr/testcore/')
response = solr.search(q='*:*')
print("response")
print(response)
```

[image: solr response]

This code used to work but now I get a 401 reply from SOLR ... just like that, no changes have been made to the python virtual env containing mysolr or the SOLR setup. Still...something must have changed somewhere but I'm out of clues.

*What could be the causes of a SOLR 401 reponse?*

Additional info:  This script and mor advanced script do work on another PC, just not on the one I am working on. Also, adding "/select?q=*:*" behind the url in the browser does return the correct results. So the SOLR is setup correctly, it has probably something to do with my computer itself. Could windows settings (of any kind) have an impact on how SOLR responds to requests from python? The python env itself has been reinstalled several times to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the Solr log show anything useful?

Comment: .. and do a request to /select?q=*:* return anything?

Comment: It returns: <SolrResponse status=401> when I do it from python. But in the browser adding " /select?q=*:*" does return results so the SOLR itself is setup correctly. Also I have found out this exact script (and others more advanced) work on another pc. I made a new clean python virtual env with only what was needed to run this script but to no avail. Could this have something to do with windows environnement variables or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was: proxy.

If this exact situation was ever to occur to someone and you are behind a proxy, check if your HTTP and HTTPS environmental variables are not set. If they are... this might cause the python session to try using the proxy while it shouldn't (connecting to localhost via proxy).

It didn't cause any trouble for months but out of the blue it did so whether you encounter this or not might be dependent on how your IT setup your proxy or made some other changes...somewhere.

thank you everyone!